Laravel 10 + Blade - Image and String under same input key not working
My Blade File -
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="attribute_type_value[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="attribute_type_value[]">

<input type="file" class="form-control" name="attribute_type_value[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="attribute_type_value[]">

I have 4 fields as shown.
In controller (beginning of store method),
dd($request->all());
gives =>
array:3 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\GuidelineController.php:421
  "_token" => "SdTIs78s642zhupVD9diK7m6cA1hjVzeYjI6aOl5"
  "attribute_type_key" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "image"
    1 => "rich-text"
    2 => "image"
    3 => "rich-text"
  ]
  "attribute_type_value" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 
Illuminate\Http
\
UploadedFile {#1439 ▶}
    1 => 
Illuminate\Http
\
UploadedFile {#1440 ▶}
  ]
]

I tried different validation rules, like conditionally checking for string or images which wasnt the actual issue i guess
EXPECTED RESULT :
"attribute_type_key" => array:4 []
"attribute_type_value" => array:4 []

But getting:
"attribute_type_key" => array:4 []
"attribute_type_value" => array:2 []


Please send your blade form completely .

Do you need to have mixed types with the same name?

You can try this :
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{{route('test')}}">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file_attribute_type_value[]">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text_attribute_type_value[]">

    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file_attribute_type_value[]">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text_attribute_type_value[]">

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
</body>

Sample output:
[output in dd()]: https://i.sstatic.net/kEiZdYMb.png

Could you explain what you did and why it will work? It might be that the names being the same, although unusual, is what the OP wanted.

The input types are different so the values will be different , so we need different names for each value with same type
